# How to force (fast ring) download of Win10 preview build?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-preview

How Do I force my computer with 1511 Win10 to download the latest preview build?
How is this triggered internally?

In my case I decided to put one PC from slow ring to fast ring because I want to use it as dedicated test PC.

Comment: I just tested: setting system time 2 months ahead, check for updates, reboot, check updates, date back in current time, check updates, and now it pulls the latest build.... by coincidence? or actual trick?

Comment: Only Microsoft can answer this question.

Comment: It worked fine but now the update fails because an applemnt.Sys driver causes bsod

Answer (score 0):

"the registry ring time stamps need to be changed so RingTimestamp and bRingTimestamp if you just changed rings and the enablepreviewbuild if you just switch to being an insider"

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update/insider-program-stuck-at-release-10586-windows/6d3f0621-dc84-4bd0-a468-2219a26e5a34?msgId=7b4c89b5-96b4-4b72-b520-7472d87d76c4